# SQL 1005 error when running Laravel 4 migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up a `comments` table with a foreign key to the `users` table with Laravel 4's schema builder, like so:

```
Schema::create('comments', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

But when I run the migration, I get the following error message:

```
[Exception]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'streamr.#sql-16fc_89' (errno: 150)
(SQL: alter table `comments` add constraint comments_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`)) (Bindings: array ())
```

As far as I can tell, this is because the `id` column of the `users` table is `int(10)`, and `$table->integer('user_id')` makes an `int(11)` column causing the foreign key to fail due to incompatible column types. However, when I try to set the length of the integer column I'm creating it doesn't work:

```
$table->integer('user_id', 10);
```

Is there any way to get around this? Seems strange to me that Laravel's schema builder will build a `int(10)` column for primary keys and not make them compatible with `integer` columns :/

**Edit:** I've also made sure the tables are InnoDB, and they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$table->increments('id')` produces an unsigned integer.  Integers are not compatible with unsigned integers when setting up a foreign key.

Try this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

From laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys):

> **Note**: When creating a foreign key that references an incrementing integer, remember to always make the foreign key column unsigned.

Comment: if you use `->onDelete('set null');` like `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');`, it probably needs to set foreign column nullable: `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();`